# Open-source download statistics

Tags: open-source, github, statistics, sourceforge

Is sourceforge really the only host to let me see the countries from which my code is being downloaded and the OS they are using?

Is there a way on github, or other open-source hosts, to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, considering the kind of data [GitHub offered to be analyzed with Google BigQuery](https://github.com/blog/1112-data-at-github) (and its [GitHub Data Challenge](https://github.com/blog/1118-the-github-data-challenge))

You can see here an example of the kind of visualization you can produce from those data (no data bout countries in there):
[GitHub data analysis](http://www.r-bloggers.com/github-data-analysis/)

For instance:

> The analysis of creation of new repository shows, that the pattern of busy or calm hours remains over the years.

[image: creation of new repository]

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can user Bob know the distribution of the users of his project FooBar, hosted at https://github.com/bob/FooBar, among Windows, OS X, and Linux?

Comment: @user700648 my point was that, beside the 'events' of GitHub v3 aPI: http://developer.github.com/v3/events/types/ , you won't find other informations. So if those 'events' doesn't allow you to detect, for instance, the OS used, you won't be able to get the distribution of users you mentioned.

Comment: @user700648 Basically, http://developer.github.com/v3/events/types/ is as specific as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are looking for Google Analytics for Github statistics maybe [GA-Beacon](https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon) could be a solution.